# zsh completion doesn't correct ? (question mark) in paths

Tags: osx, zsh, autocomplete

So, I've been pretty happy with my zsh completion and correction configuration for a while now, with this being a major exception.

Configured as I have it, the shell routinely catches and corrects incorrect case when I perform tab completion. For instance, it will easily correct `ls ~/DOcuments/somedir`
to `ls ~/Documents/somedir`.

However, it is every bit as easy, and notably for precisely the same reasons and in precisely the same manner, to type (for example) `cd ~?Somedir<tab>`. Of course, the user might reasonably expect the question mark to be considered as a possible mistake, such that (in the absence of a better match) his entry will be corrected to `cd ~/Somedir`.

But instead, I get this sort of error message:

```
No matches for: `user' or `named directory'
```

Or, if I've entered a couple characters after the question mark, I might get a list of suggestions which, I assume (based on their content and the above error message), are active user processes.

Does anybody know an easy way for me to get the desired result?

Comment: I don't think the question mark is supposed to match slashes.

Comment: Perhaps not. But I want it to, and my tools are "supposed" to do whatever I want them to do. The only correct behavior is behavior which the user finds desirable. QED.

Comment: Given the way autocorrect works internally (*after* the input has been parsed into “home of `?Somedir`”), I think this would require significant changes to the code.

Comment: Also the completer can be configured  to expand globs and give you all the files matching the patterns (for instance `*.txt<Tab>` gives you a list of txt files to choose from). `?` is a globbing character.